# packing an array of 3 values in buffer

Tags: c++, c, memory, bit-manipulation, information-theory

I have the following problem I am unable to solve gracefully.

I have a data type that can take 3 possible values (0,1,2).
I have an array of 20 element of this data type.

As I want to encode the information on the least amount of memory, I did the following :

- consider that each element can take up to 4 values (2 bits)
- each `char` holds 8 bits, so I can put 4 times an element
- 5 `char` holds 40 bits, so I can store 20 elements.

I have done this and it works time.

However I'm interested evaluating the space gained by using the fact that my element can only take 3 values and not 4.
Every possible combination gives us 3 to the 20th power, which is 3,486,784,401. However 256 to the 4th power gives us 4,294,967,296 , which is greater. This means I could encode my data on 4 `char` .

Is there an generic method to do the 2nd idea here ? The 1st idea is simple to implement with bit mask / bit shifts. However since 3 values doesn't fit in an integer number of bits, I have no idea how to encode / decode any of these values into an array of 4 char.

Do you have any idea or reference on how it's done ? I think there must be a general method. If anything I'm interested about the feasability of this

edit : this could be simplified to : how to store 5 values from 0 to 2 into 1 byte only (as 256 >= 3^5 = 243)

Comment: what comes into my mind first is doing a base conversion from base 3 (original values) to base 2, for a number which has 20 digits in base 3

Comment: there's also things like matlab / octave that have a c/c++ api with functions like base2dec / dec2base http://octave.sourceforge.net/octave/function/base2dec.html which could do the job for you...

Comment: on the other hand, the 2nd method only makes sense if you have serious memory restraints... the first one is more easy to calculate/read/write/handle. If space is low you could also think about using a compressing algorithm like lzma if you want to let's say send things over network etc...

Comment: How many bits are you willing to waste to make addressing individual elements easier? As you have noted, using 2 bits allows for 4 values, but you only need 3 values, so you waste 1/2 bit out of 2 bits (1/4). You can place 5 of these values into a 4 bit nibble, wasting 1/2 bit out of 4 bits (1/16), but then extracting and setting the individual value is harder. Make your life easier, and waste the 1/2 bit out of 2 bits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to do what you said using 4 bytes.  Assume that you store the 20 values into a single `int32_t` called `value`, here is how you would extract any particular element:

```
element[0] = value % 3;
element[1] = (value / 3) % 3;
element[2] = (value / 9) % 3;
...
element[19] = (value / 1162261467) % 3; // 1162261467 = 3 ^ 19
```

Or as a loop:

```
for (i=0;i<20;i++) {
    element[i] = value % 3;
    value /= 3;
}
```

To build `value` from `element`, you would just do the reverse, something like this:

```
value = 0;
for (i=19;i>=0;i--)
    value = value * 3 + element[i];
```

Comment: thanks a lot ! But do you have any idea about the code to specifically set a single element into the 32 bits int , without changing the rest ?

Comment: would it hurt if you read the value to elements, perform the change and then write it back? I think you can't prevent the system to perform a write operation on the whole int anyways...

Answer (score 0):

There is a generic way to figure out how much bits you need:

If your data type has *N* different values, then you need *log(N) / log(2)* bits to store this value. For instance in your example, *log(3) / log(2)* equals 1.585 bits.

Of course in reality you will to pack a fixed amount of values in an integer number of bits, so you have to multiply this 1.585 with that amount and round up. For instance if you pack 5 of them:

*1.585 × 5 = 7.925*, meaning that 5 of your values just fit in one 8-bit `char`.

The way to unpack the values has been shown in JS1's answer. The generic formula for unpacking is *element[i] = (value / (N ^ i) ) mod N*

Final note, this is only meaningful if you really need to optimize memory usage. For comparison, here are some popular ways people pack these value types. Most of the time the extra space taken up is not a problem.

- an array of `bool`: uses 8 bits to store one `bool`. And a lot of people really dislike the behavior of `std::vector<bool>`.
- `enum Bla { BLA_A, BLA_B, BLA_C};` an array or vector of `Bla` probably uses 32 bits per element (`sizeof(Bla) == sizeof(int)`).